# Facebook Like box aligned below Twitter/G+... but only on mobile?

Tags: facebook, alignment, facebook-like

I have a Facebook Like/Share box (copied from the code on Facebook) in between my Twitter and Google+ icons.

On the [browser version of my page](http://www.kamboclear.com/test-page/) (scroll most of the way down to see the buttons), everything is aligned perfectly. On my iPhone, the Facebook box is about 20px below the rest. I have tried all sorts of HTML and CSS coding, and nothing seems to get the mobile version to look right.

I was able to set up a class to move the Facebook box up by 20px, which made it look great on the iPhone but way too high on the Chrome version.

Answer (score 0):

Check by adding the width attribute to the anchor tags of p element,

```
p a {
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Hey Siddaram, that didn't seem to change anything. If my understanding is correct, I think there's a formatting issue with Facebook's iframe

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can't modify facebook plugin, you have to align other tags according to it. Try changing the sizes of google and twitter images, so that they would fit with facebook.